# Restart the p:poll component if stopping it

Tags: primefaces

I am scanning the QR code image with the photoCam component. Therefore, the `oncapture()` method is being called in the `viewEventStatusController` which returns a String. The String `QrCode` is being
rendered inside the `qrInputText`. At this point I am stoping the `poll` by setting `pollStop=true`. I want to restart the poll if the user clicks a new item in the menu if he clicks
the default `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Barcodeleser im Lager 1" itemValue="0" />` one it must be stoped.

How can I restart the `poll` component? I have tried to set the `pollStop=false` inside the `viewEventStatusController.changeSelectOnMenue` but it is being restarted.

```
           <h:form id="rqScannerForm">
              <p:growl id="QRgrowl" showDetail="true" /> 
              <p:selectOneMenu  id="selectOneMenu" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 20px; height: 30px;" styleClass="MyOneMenu" scrollHeight="150" 
                 value="#{viewEventStatusController.eventStatusId}"  disabled="#{!eventStatusController.isEntityEditable}" autoWidth="false" >
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Barcodeleser im Lager 1" itemValue="0" />
                 <f:selectItems value="#{viewEventStatusController.eventStatusList}" var="eventStatus" itemValue="#{eventStatus.id}" itemLabel="#{eventStatus.objectId}" />
                 <p:ajax event="change" update="@(*[id*=chatEntriesDataPanel], idleMonitor, growl)" resetValues="true"  listener="#{viewEventStatusController.changeSelectOnMenue()}" />
              </p:selectOneMenu>
              <br/>

              <!-- Web Cam Scanner -->
              <p:photoCam widgetVar="photoCamWidgetVar" listener="#{viewEventStatusController.oncapture}"  width="360" height="306" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 20px;" 
                 update="@(*[id*=qrInputText], idleMonitor, growl), @(*[id*=QRgrowl], idleMonitor, growl)" >
                 <p:poll widgetVar="photoCamPoll" onstart="PF('photoCamWidgetVar').capture()"  interval="2" autoStart="false" stop="#{viewEventStatusController.pollStop}"/>
              </p:photoCam>
              <br/> 
              <p:inputText id="qrInputText" value="#{viewEventStatusController.qrCode}" style="width: 67%; height: 25px; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 20px;"/>
              <p:commandButton action="#{viewEventStatusController.callServiceAgent(null, -1)}"  update="@(*[id*=chatEntriesDataPanel], idleMonitor, growl)"    process="@form" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"  style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 20px; width:12%; height: 35px;" styleClass="ui-btn-inline ui-btn-right" >
              </p:commandButton>
           </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be changing the variable `pollStop` in your method but I think you aren't updating the `p:poll` component. Try putting an id on the poll and adding it to your `p:ajax` `update`.